# cancan rails code understanding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I am unable to debug some of cancancan code and looking for some help.

```
can :update, Message do |m|
  false
end
```

But strangely cancancan always return true and i am unable to debug the issue.Here is a small piece of relevant cancancan code

```
   rule.rb
    def matches_conditions?(action, subject, extra_args)
         if  
           ...
          elsif @block && !subject_class?(subject)
            @block.call(subject, *extra_args)
          end
        end
```

I can see that the @block.call is made and it return false but this piece of code in the ability.rb does not make sense to me

```
match = subject.map do |subject|
        relevant_rules_for_match(action, subject).detect do |rule|
          rule.matches_conditions?(action, subject, extra_args)
        end
      end.compact.first

      match ? match.base_behavior : false
```

The base_behaviour is never set after initialization, and set to true at initialization, how would base_behaviour of a rule would ever return false.

The helper function is called

```
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.can? :update ,@message
```

Comment: Are you checking `can?(:update, Message)` or `can?(:update, @message)` in your view?

Comment: You have to restart your server, each time you make changes to your `ability.rb`. Also can you paste the code, where you are using `can?` helper method.

Comment: @kddeisz  i have updated the questions. Thanks

Comment: @HassanAkram I have update the question.

Comment: Got it there was a overriding ability. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it there was a overriding ability